# How does Apache Hive work on Amazon?

Tags: apache, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, hive

I'm looking to figure out the mechanics of Apache Hive hosted by Amazon. I'm assuming, it substitutes HDFS with S3 and Hadoop MapReduce with EMR. Are my assumptions correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mostly correct. I would say that it is most convenient way to run Hive on amazon is 
replacing HDFS with S3. It is practical since data is living on S3 and we can run Hadoop / Hive cluster on demand.  Some drawback is slow write performance - so doing data transformations will be slow. Doing aggregations - is mostly fine
In the same time there are other configurations: 
Build HDFS over local drives. 
Build HDFS over EBS volumes. 
Each one with their trade offs.

Comment: 1. How much slower will write performance be compared to the other methods you suggested?2. Which one of the options is the cheapest i.e. will consume least AWS resources? 3. I am wondering if using the cloudera AMI would be a good substitute for building HDFS over local drives.

Comment: It depends on kind of instance - since they have different network connection to storage. But roughly I would estimate as x10